# What is the procedure to change FPTP to PR system in India?

Tags: election, india

Does a constitutional amendment is required to change the First Past the Post System to Proportional Representation System in India? If so, what are the steps needed to do that?

Does FPTP mode of electoral system come under "Basic Structure of the Constitution"?

Answer (score 1):

### Source of Requirements

No, the first-past-the-post system is not a Constitutional requirement in India.

The Constitution says:

> ... the  House  of  the  People  shall  consist  of—
>   (
>   a
>   )  not  more  than
>   4
>   [five  hundred  and  thirty
>   members]  chosen  by  direct  election  from  territorial
>   constituencies  in  the  States,  and
>   (
>   b
>   ) not more than 
>   5
>   [twenty members] to represent
>   the  Union  territories,  chosen  in  such  manner  as
>   Parliament  may  by  law  provide. ([Section 81 of Indian Constitution](http://lawmin.nic.in/coi/coiason29july08.pdf))

The manner of election is left to Parliament to decide. The Constitution also allows for an electoral commission, which implements the electoral system and make other decisions related to the process.

I wasn't able to locate the source of the first-past-the-post system. It might be either a Parliamentary act, decision by the electoral commission, or something else - but it isn't a Constitutional requirement.

### How to Change

I covered Indian legislative process in [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11881/what-would-be-a-procedure-or-legislative-steps-that-have-to-be-taken-for-remov/11882#11882).  Since this is not a Constitutional amendment, the bill would require a simple majority of voters in each house to pass.

Comment: And there is the problem: The people in the houses got their seats through the FPTP system. Any change of voting procedure which might result in a greater plurality would mean that they would lose power. That problem applies to any democracy on the world.

Comment: @Philipp - that is beyond the scope of the question.  It's definitely not generally true of democracies, but I don't know if it's true in this one case or not.  I think the literature on transaction costs would be very illustrative.